# Kernel underworking questions and execution costs

Tags: optimization, opencl

I have two questions:

1. Is it better to make a kernel overwork or underwork? Let's say I want to calculate a difference image with only 4 GPU cores. Should I consider any pixel of my image to be calculated independently by 1 thread or Should I make 1 thread calculate a whole line of my image? I dont know which solution is the most optimized to use. I already vectorized the first option (which was impelmented) but I only gain some ms, it is not very significative.
2. My second question is about the execution costs of a kernel. I know how to measure any OpenCL command queue task (copy, write, read, kernel...) but I think there is a time taken by the host to load the kernel to the GPU cores. Is there any way to evaluate it?

Baptiste

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1)

Typically you'd process a single item in a kernel. If you process multiple items, you need to do them in the right order to ensure coalesced memory access or you'll be slower than doing a single item (the solution to this is to process a column per work item instead of a row).

Another reason why working on multiple items can be slower is that you might leave compute units idle. For example, if you process scanlines on a 1000x1000 image with 700 compute units, the work will be chunked into 700 work items and then only 300 work items (leaving 400 idle).

A case where you want to do lots of work in a single kernel is if you're using shared local memory. For example, if you load a look-up table (LUT) into SLM, you should use it for an entire scanline or image.

(2)

I'm sure this is a non-zero amount of time but it is negligible. Kernel code is pretty small. The driver handles moving it to the GPU, and also handles pushing parameter data onto the GPU. Both are very fast, and likely happen while other kernels are running, so are "free".